# How to refresh Bloomberg data in a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I have a function to insert a Bloomberg formula into a cell

```vb
for i = 1 To Data.UsedRange.Row.Count 
    Data.Cells(i, 12).Forumla="=BDP(""" & Data.Cells(i,2).value & " EQUITTY" & _
      """,""EQY_WEIGHTED_AVG_PX"",""VWAP_START_TIME=" & startTime & """,""VWAP_END_TIME="& endTime & _ 
      """,""VWAP_START_DT=" & startDate & """,""VWAP_END_DT=" & endDate & """)"
    Call Application.OnTime(Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"),"ProcessData")
next i


Public Sub ProcessData()
    For i = 1 To Data.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        if Data.cells(i,12).Value = "#N/A Requesting Data..." Then
            Call Application.OnTime(Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "ProcessData")
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The function gets values from a sheet, then creates a worksheet that contains the output.
I loop though all rows, to get stock name and such, then insert the VWAP Bloomberg formula into the cell.

I am getting

> N/A Requesting Data...

I know that Bloomberg takes time to load the data; that's why I tried to call `Application.OnTime`. It only works once in a while.

E.g. I run the first time with two orders, and it works. If I run another order, it gets back to N/A Requesting Data...

Comment: It appears that Bloomberg broke `Application.OnTime` calls with their 21 Sept 2020 API update – see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64124682/2662901)

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look to this post:

[Wait until Excel finishes populating Bloomberg data using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952324/wait-until-excel-finishes-populating-bloomberg-data-using-vba/52952573#52952573)

I've found a trick to wait until all the data requested are sent back from Bloomberg to my Excel, and after that you can safely call your `ProcessData()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you are suggesting to use IFERROR to change the value to 0, and just call     Application.Calculate
    Application.RTD.RefreshData
    DoEvents

Comment: Yes. Try this and let us know